# "window.location.href" open link in new tab

Tags: javascript

I am using below code for loading another web page url through button. This code is working correctly. Please suggest if we can open that url in new tab using window.location.href only?.

HTML:

```
<button class="float-left submit-button" id="myButton" type="button" target="_blank">Submit</button>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById("myButton").onclick = function ()
{
    var labelVal = $("#study").text().trim();
    window.location.href= "/oGPGWW4EPjrLZZbl0_/analysis?file=/";";                
};
```

Comment: "_using window.location.href only_" Not possible, unless you already have a tab opened.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-and-not-a-new-window-using-javascript

Comment: Instead of `location.href`, use `window.open(url)`. Try like that.

Comment: You shouldn't need to use the `open` function if you're using proper markup. A link would work, or a form worth a submit button.

Comment: @Teemu  Yes, one tab is already opened. if we click on button , i need to open the new url in another tab using window.location.href

Comment: But `window` in `window.location.href` refers to the window where the script is executed, instead of `window` you've to use a reference to that other tab. The question is like you'd ask how to hit nails to concrete with bare hands, who wouldn't answer "use a hammer instead" ...

Answer (score 0):

```
function(){
var win = window.open(url, '_blank');
 win.focus();
}
```

Comment: How does this fullfil "_using window.location.href only_"?

Comment: can't possible with window.location.href opening new tab?

Comment: @JanakiRam No, it's not.